# How to remove from a string everything which is not a digit, a dot or a minus in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a quick `regex` that removes every character which is not a digit, a dot or a minus from a string?

Comment: what is the code that you tried

Comment: You should be able to [figure it out](http://regexpal.com/).

Comment: @Pointy yes i know, i just needed a quick help because i'm not very good with regular expressions. I need to study them , i will start :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, "");
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q7rvt/)

```
var str = "43gf..--.65";
var result = str.replace(/[^\d.\-]/g, "");​ 
alert(result); // "43..--.65"
```

[An excellent regex cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2/png/) which can help you learn `regex` really fast.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the cheatsheet! :)

Comment: @gdoron - Can you explain why don't you have to escape the dot and the minus sign, like: `/[^\d\.\-]/g` ?

Comment: @MikeC - the minus sign can be a special character inside a character class as it represents a range, e.g. [A-Z] and as such might be misinterpreted elsewhere - it's best to put it as the first character or escape, i.e. I'd suggest [^-\d.]

Comment: @MikeC. I asked your's question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397968/escape-dot-in-a-regex-range). Lets see...