# spliting text into array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to split when getting `,` or `.` in text in javascript.

My text is like this:

> The cats climbed the tall tree.In this sentence, $U_SEL{} is a noun.

I want array as:

```
1.The cats climbed the tall tree.
2.In this sentence
3.$U_SEL{}
4.is a noun
```

Comment: why would you split between `$U_SEL{}` and `is a noun.` - there is no , or . there ... `.split(/[.,]/)`

Comment: If you want to isolate $U_SEL{} you need to think about how to identify that part of the string. For example, if you first split on , . and then search for strings that contain a variable that starts with $, and then split that string on spaces....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string with multiple separators in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression for this challenge will be.

```
var text = "The cats climbed the tall tree.In this sentence, $U_SEL{} is a noun."
var regex = /[.,]/;
text.split(regex);
```

> FOR MORE INFORMATION ABOUT `regex` VISIT
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `regex`. To split on `{}` first replace **that** with `{},` or `{}.`, then try split.

```js
var str = "The cats climbed the tall tree.In this sentence, $U_SEL{} is a noun";
str = str.replace("{}", "{},");

//Array with splitted value
var result = str.split(/[,.]/g);

//Printing the result array
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var text = "The cats climbed the tall tree.In this sentence, $U_SEL{}, is a noun";
    var spliteds = text.split(/[\.,]/);

    alert(spliteds[0]);
    alert(spliteds[1]);
    alert(spliteds[2]);
    alert(spliteds[3]);
</script>
```

Comment: There is no `,` after `{}`. Check the question again!

Answer (score 0):

```
 'The cats climbed the tall tree.In this sentence, $U_SEL{} is a noun.'.split(/[\.,]/)
```

would return:

```
Array [ "The cats climbed the tall tree", "In this sentence", " $U_SEL{} is a noun", "" ]
```

Take a look at [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: You learn something new every day. I was adamant you would be wrong, but you're not :P 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397968/escape-dot-in-a-regex-range

Comment: I always forget that myself

Answer (score 0):

A Regular Expression is your best option in this case. All the above posts are already correctly covering this way of solving your issue. I am just leaving here another approach that will provide what you are after if you have no idea of how Regular Expressions work.

Take into account though that **RegExp is quite optimal choice** in your scenario. The above code is mostly to show how it can be done without using RegExps. (Not to mention that it will get chaotic adding more delimiters)

```js
var myString = "The cats climbed the tall tree.In this sentence, $U_SEL{} , is a noun";
var mySplitString = myString.split(",");
var myFinalArray = new Array();

mySplitString.forEach(function(part){
  var myTemp = part.split(".");
  myTemp.forEach(function(key){
    myFinalArray.push(key);
  });
});

console.log(myFinalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe split is not accurate because splitting requires a single character delimiter and there is no delimiter for the third element.

Trying capturing rather than splitting may work better (though I don't know if it is wise from performance point of view).

You could try this:

```js
var pattern = /(([^.,]+?)([.,]|\{\})) */g;

var captures = [];
var s = 'First capture.Second capture, $THIRD_CAPTURE{} fourth capture.';
while ( (match = pattern.exec(s)) != null ) {
 if (match[3] == "." || match[3] == ",") {
  captures.push(match[2]);
 } else {
  captures.push(match[1]);
 }
}
console.log(captures);

var captures = [];
var s = 'The cats climbed the tall tree.In this sentence, $U_SEL{} is a noun.';
while ( (match = pattern.exec(s)) != null ) {
 if (match[3] == "." || match[3] == ",") {
  captures.push(match[2]);
 } else {
  captures.push(match[1]);
 }
}
console.log(captures);
```

The principle is as below.

- Capture blocks of either a part of the sentence ended by a dot or a comma, without inner dot or comma, or ending with empty brackets pair
- Within each block, capture both the content and the ending (either a dot, a comma or an empty brackets pair)

For each resulting match, you have three captures:

- At index 1, the first block
- At index 3, the ending
- At index 2, the content without the ending

Then, according to the ending, either the match of idx 1 or 2 is stored.

You could modify the loop selecting the match to get exactly what you want, with the dot on the first capture and not on the last one, unless it is a typo.